# Is it possible to update an existing field in an index through mapping in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, put, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I've already created an index, and it contains data from my `MySQL` database. I've got few fields which are `string` in my table, where I need them as different types (`integer` & `double`) in `Elasticsearch`.

So I'm aware that I could do it through `mapping` as follows:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "userid": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        },
        "responsecode": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "chargeamount": {
          "type": "double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I've tried this when I'm creating the index as a new one. What I wanted to know is how can I update an existing field (ie: `chargeamount` in this scenario) using `mapping` as a `PUT`?

Is this possible? Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a mapping type has been created, you're very constrained on what you can update. According to the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings), the only changes you can make to an existing mapping after it's been created are the following, but changing a field's type is not one of them:

> In general, the mapping for existing fields cannot be updated. There
>   are some exceptions to this rule. For instance:
>
> - new properties can be added to Object datatype fields.
> - new multi-fields can be added to existing fields.
> - doc_values can be disabled, but not enabled.
> - the ignore_above parameter can be updated.